# Make first-letter of label uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edit:**

It seems to be a futile attempt as there doesn't seem to be a way to make the first letter uppercase if there is a pseudo-element in the way, and unfortuntely the pseudo-element cannot be moved or removed as the below attempted answers would like it to be. In any case, thank you very much for all the help.

---

I've attached a code example just to make things a bit easier.

I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly or if this is a futile attempt. Hope to god JavaScript is not needed for something as simple as this.

Thank you very much on any insights!

```css
label span:before {
  display: inline-block;
    content: " ";
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

label {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

label::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>
    TESTING
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: make sure, all label tag would get capitalized, if you want specific then apply nested class and parent child relation of tags.

Comment: Is the text meant to be Uppercased on code?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make the first letter to be uppercase, and the rest of the word lowercase.  You also need to make label display: inline-block;

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afg3eegs/1/

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

label::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <span>
        TESTING
    </span>
</label>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @idmean nothing wrong with JSFiddle. It's a lot more flexible than SO snippets

Comment: @Phil For me it is wrong. I don't like clicking on links and JSFiddle needs ages to load.

Comment: didn't know about runnable snippets, added just now.  thanks

Comment: @link Please look at my actual code above more specifically the pseudo-element that's in there. I realize that without the pseudo-element `::first-letter` would work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, in order to make the first letter of the `<span>` element uppercase, you need to move the `::before` pseudo-element to the `<label>` and use `::first-letter` pseudo-element on the `<span>` instead:

```css
label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: " ";
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

label, label span {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

label span::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>
    TESTING
  </span>
</label>
```

Notice that [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter) pseudo-element is not applicable on non-replaced inline level elements.

Comment: Thanks Mimi, however, the pseudo-element is generated outside of my own control

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work for you.

```
label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work if the text is all caps (as in OP's code). Also, this would capitalise multiple words which doesn't exactly fit OP's requirement

Comment: And also, it leaves `TESTING` as `TESTING`

Comment: in that case css would not help i guess, as you want complete sentence to be capitalized. Following URL would help, i am sure.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

If the text "TESTING" is already in capital you cannot make it capitalize using css as far as i know.
you should try to do it using javascript.
or you may try using display:inline-block property as suggested above.